# <ng-template>,<ng-content> are directives in angular or just angular element?

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

while going through angular course the trainer told ng-template is a directive whereas angular has 3 types of directives-attribute, structural and component.So I am confused here what exactly it is?

Answer (score 5):

```
Generally `<ng-template>` is used along with structural directives like( *ngIF, *ngFor etc ), like you can write a if condition like this



<div *ngIf="condition; else elseBlock">
     True Block
    </div>

    <ng-template #elseBlock>
     <div>
      Else block
     </div>
    </ng-template>

<ng-content> is used for content projection. pls find the below example.

<app-new-component>
 <h1>Hey, here is the example code...</h1>
</app-new-component>
```

Here we place a custom code inside the `<app-new-component>`, now we can use the `<ng-content>` to project that code inside the app-new-component.html

app-new-component.html be like this

```
<div class="header-wrap">
 <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Jyothi  for explaining it in detail

Answer (score 2):

The `<ng-template>` element is an Angular element for rendering HTML. It is never displayed directly. In fact, before rendering the view, Angular replaces the  and its contents with a comment.

Official docs : https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#the-ng-template

The `ng-content` core directive allows for component designs where certain internal details of the template are not hidden inside the component but instead are provided as an input, which in certain cases really simplifies the design

Comment: Thanks, Suhag for quick answer.